# Adding the index after every push() call

Tags: arrays, perl, debugging, push

I'm using the Perl `push` on an array, but every time I push something on the array, it also pushes the item's index as well.
I am doing the same action on 2 arrays at the same time, and one pushes as expected, but the other does not.
What could be causing this unexplained behavior?

```
if ($var->{color} == 1) {
    push @x, $var->{variable}.'-l';  
    push @y, $var->{variable}.'-p';
}
else {
    push @x, '__',
    push @y, '__',
}
```

`y` has the data as expected, but `x` does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want semicolons, not commas here:

```
push @x, '__';
push @y, '__';
```